# Google Tag manager is showing permission denied error while adding HTML Code

Tags: html, google-tag-manager, permission-denied

I am trying to add HTML tracking script on my website through Google tag manager but it is not allowing me to do so.. and showing 'Permission Denied' error. Although I have admin rights of the account.

Can anyone help me in identifying and fixing the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. As it turned out I needed another administrator to change my account access to view only, save, and then change the setting back to view/edit/manage.

Failing that, you can create a new container.